# Deixar checado um option ao selecionar opção de outro select JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá, tenho 1º select option:

```
<select name="auto" id="auto">
  <option value="">S/N</option>
  <option value="S">Sim</option>
  <option value="N">Não</option>
</select>
```

E tenho também 2º select option:

```
<select name="conta" id="conta">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="+">Somar</option>
  <option value="*">Multiplica</option>
</select>
```

Tenho esse `script` mas não está dando certo, ele não faz nenhuma ação ao selecionar o `option` auto.

```
$('#auto').change(function () {
   const auto = $('#auto').val();
   const conta = $('#conta').val();
   $('#auto').val('');
}).change();
```

Gostaria que quando escolhesse qualquer opção do **1º** `select` *auto*, ele colocasse o **2º** `select` *conta* na opção Selecione, caso tenha qualquer outra opção já selecionada, tem como?

Comment: É porque é o seguinte, se eu escolher qualquer opção no **select 2** e voltar no **select 1** e escolher qualquer opção é pra o **select 2** ele voltar ao estado padrão, entendeu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

aqui está:

```js
$('#auto').change(function(){
  $('#conta').val('');
});
```

```html
<select name="auto" id="auto">
  <option value="">S/N</option>
  <option value="S">Sim</option>
  <option value="N">Não</option>
</select>

<select name="conta" id="conta">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="+">Somar</option>
  <option value="*">Multiplica</option>
</select>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Desculpe @augusto Vasques pela pergunta direta sem ter descriminado algo sobre o assunto, vou editar a pergunta informando o que eu já tinha produzido e não deu certo.

Comment: @AristófanesMelo, faça isso e você e Mike ganham meu upvote.

Comment: Editado @augusto Vasques.

Comment: @AristófanesMelo, Está aí. alguém havia lhe dado o negativo, mais o meu positivo ficou em zero: https://imgur.com/a/jTACk6C

Comment: Vlw e obrigado!